# How to maintain a scroll position when I close the pop-up container?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the close button in the pop up container, the scroll position goes back to the top.

This is my HTML and JavaScript code for the pop up container:

```js
var scrollPosition;

function openPopup(title, Exercise1, Exercise2, Exercise3, Exercise4, Exercise5, Exercise6) {
  // Save the current scroll position
  scrollPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  // Set the content of the popup
  document.getElementById('popup-title').textContent = title;
  document.getElementById('Exercise1').textContent = 'Exercise: ' + Exercise1;
  document.getElementById('Exercise2').textContent = 'Exercise: ' + Exercise2;
  document.getElementById('Exercise3').textContent = 'Exercise: ' + Exercise3;
  document.getElementById('Exercise4').textContent = 'Exercise: ' + Exercise4;
  document.getElementById('Exercise5').textContent = 'Exercise: ' + Exercise5;
  document.getElementById('Exercise6').textContent = 'Exercise: ' + Exercise6;

  // Display the popup
  document.getElementById('popup-container').style.display = 'flex';

  // Add an event listener to track changes in the scroll position
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}

function closePopup() {
  // Hide the popup
  document.getElementById('popup-container').style.display = 'none';

  // Remove the scroll event listener
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}

function handleScroll() {
  // Restore the scroll position
  window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-container" class="popup-container">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <!-- Add content for exercises -->
    <h3 id="popup-title">Exercise Details</h3>
    <p id="Exercise1"></p>
    <p id="Exercise2"></p>
    <p id="Exercise3"></p>
    <p id="Exercise4"></p>
    <p id="Exercise5"></p>
    <p id="Exercise6"></p>
    <!-- Close button -->
    <a href="#" class="close-btn" onclick="closePopup()">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it so that when I close the button, it stays at its scroll position.